# Android list available serialport/comport devices

Tags: android, serial-port

I want to get a list of all available com ports of an Android device, so that I can choose to which com port I will be sending data.

I need the path to available com ports as so:

```
/dev/ttymxc0
/dev/ttymxc1
/dev/ttymxc2
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a close enough answer.

In serial port API there is a class Serial Port Finder which does just what I want. Well at least generally (it returns USB, sdcard more or less all ports but it will do)